# How to upload .pdf .doc .txt files to server(mysql database) using Android

Tags: android, arrays, android-asynctask

I'm facing some difficulties while uploading files to server, I need to know full code of file uploading with namevaluepair. Hear is my android code, I'm getting only my file path, how to upload it to server with reference as "nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attachment", selectedFilePath));"

```
       String selectedFilePath="downloads/harry.txt"  //(My file Path)



        InputStream is = null;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postiontitle", positiontitle));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jobtype", jobtype));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("visatype", visatype));



  if (selectedFilePath != null)
        {
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attachment", selectedFilePath));


        }


        try {


            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new                                  HttpPost("http://10.0.3.2/dfsdsd/postjob");
            // HttpPost httpPost = new 
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String rescode = String.valueOf(code);




            //result=is.toString();
            return rescode;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return "No Internet";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "No Internet";
        }
    }
```

Comment: why dont you use this library, its easy , fast , efficient and works in background

Comment: https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Retrofil or Okhttp.

```
public static final String MULTIPART_FORM_DATA = "multipart/form-data";

 @NonNull
 private RequestBody createPartFromString(String descriptionString) {  
   return RequestBody.create(
        MediaType.parse(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), descriptionString);
 }

 @NonNull
 private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, Uri fileUri) {  
// https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
// use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);

// create RequestBody instance from file
RequestBody requestFile =
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), file);

// MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple and fast then i will suggest you [ION Library](https://github.com/koush/ion/#post-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-and-read-a-string)

Post multipart/form-data and read JSON with an upload progress bar With ION :

```
Ion.with(getContext())
.load("https://koush.clockworkmod.com/test/echo")
.uploadProgressBar(uploadProgressBar)
.setMultipartParameter("goop", "noop")
.setMultipartFile("archive", "application/zip", new File("/sdcard/filename.zip"))
.asJsonObject()
.setCallback(...)
```

Comment: Multi part does not answer  `I need to know full code of file uploading with namevaluepair.`.

Comment: I suggest you to not to use NameValuePair as it is part the package org.apache which was deprecated with Android 22 and removed with Android M

Comment: Ok. Then send the file in a key value pair in a different way. That still is no multi part.